# How to searching common members in multiple lines

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, structure

I have a file like :

```
4       b_2
4       b_1
4       b_1
4       b_2
4       b_1
4       b_1
4       i_20    j_71
4       b_5
4       b_1 i_6
4       b_1
4      b_7
5    a_118   b_40    d_2 i_19
5       d_2
6      d_3
7      d_161
7   a_5 b_71    c_1 c_23    c_56    c_8 c_88
8      d_17
8       d_17
8       d_17
8       d_17
```

I need to check the line labeled with same number e.g. 4 if they have a element is shared by all the lines labeled with 4, in the above case is "none";

e.g. the line label with 8: check if the line label with 8 if they have a common element, in the above case, it is b_17...

How do I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: counts the no of line, say 8 there is 4 line. put everything (strings) for a certain label  as a vector and a set. using vector imitate a loop, then check if there is item set.count=line_no, but not sure it is wise solution.

Comment: In case that wasn't clear: we want to see the code that you wrote, we won't just give you the answer.